# Referencing DomainService class from MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We have the typical Silverlight and Silverlight.Web application that are hooked together through WCF RIA Services.  We've added an MVC project to the solution and don't want to have to write all the methods that were created in the DomainService class for us (all the inserts, updates, deletes, etc.).  When we reference the .Web project from the MVC project, we can access the DomainService class like usual, but the problem comes when we try to do changes using the Update / Insert methods.  I imagine this has to do with Visual Studio auto generating the .g.cs file in the Silverlight application, creating the DomainContext partial class.

Is there any way to use the DomainService that has been autogenerated in the .Web project from external projects and get it to make changes to the entities?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a service reference to it.  This will create the same wrappers (more or less) that you have in the Silverlight client.

Alternatively, you can refactor all the CRUD logic out of the DomainService and put it in a class library that is referenced by the Web project, as well as your MVCC app.

Answer (score 0):

this web page seems to explain how to do what you need.: http://geekswithblogs.net/bdiaz/archive/2010/04/03/using-ria-domainservices-with-asp.net-and-mvc-2.aspx